# How to write device address 28 46 04 1F 0D 00 00 74 = Sensor-1 like That for more than 10 sensors using Dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-requests, pyserial

```
import csv
from time import time
import serial


 # Your serial port might be different!

 ser = serial.Serial('COM12',baudrate=57600,bytesize=8, timeout=1)

f = open("Senosr_data.csv", "a+")


writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
while True:
s = ser.readline().decode().rstrip()// getting data  "ROM = 28 46 04 1F 0D 00 00 74 96014B467FFF0A100A value : 25.3 2699 Dc"

if s != '':
    rows = [repr(x) for x in s.split(',')]
    rows.insert(0, int(time()))
    print(rows)
    print(test_dict)
    writer.writerow(rows)
    f.flush()
```

and I am getting Output Like this from Arduino: "ROM = 28 46 04 1F 0D 00 00 74 96014B467FFF0A100A value : 25.3 2699 Dc"
so Now I wanted to print That Rom address into names for each sensor 1,2 .. and so on using a dictionary, any help or tutorial would be appreciated. Thanks In advance

Comment: Please be more clear what are you trying to achieve. Provide an example of needed output.

Comment: I am Using 10 temperature sensors using Arduino -nano and also I am using Pyserial to get the data and save it into a .csv file. so I am getting Output like "ROM = 28 46 04 1F 0D 00 00 74  96014B467FFF0A100A  Temp : 25.3 dc', so Since I am using 10 Temeparture sensors I need to write them AS a sensor-1 sensor2 instead of printing there address so i want output like this ' ROM = sensor-1  96014B467FFF0A100A  Temp : 25.3  ' , now I know I can use dictionary and can write const address={'28 46 04 1F 0D 00 00 74 ',Sensor1}, so How to implement this method I amconfusing here.

Comment: I once almost used Pyserial :) so probably will be able to get into your problem when I'll have a minute. Wait for updates soon.

Comment: Can you give me an exact example of a line that you're getting in `line = ser.readline().decode().rstrip()`?

Comment: Is it `ROM = 28 46 04 1F 0D 00 00 74 96014B467FFF0A100A Temp : 25.3 dc`?

Comment: yes  this is the output that I am getting from arduino (ROM = 28 46 04 1F 0D 00 00 74 96014B467FFF0A100A Temp : 25.3 dc)

Comment: so  "ser.readline().decode().rstrip() is the line where i am connectinng with arduino